# Is there a way to add video elements in React Native (for Android)?

Tags: android, video-streaming, react-native, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I 'm searching the docs, but haven't succeeded yet to find a sample code. 
I need to play videos from my stream server.  Is there any way? or may be react-js does not support videos on android yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep. Took me a while to figure out, but the solution is easy.

Use [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) component which is cross-platform iOS and Android.

*Implementation:* 
Couldn't be simpler...

```
<Video source={{ uri: 'http://STREAM_URL/playlist.m3u8' }} />
```

Tips for playing live HLS .m3u8 streams on iOS and Android:

*On iOS:*
Be sure to allow the stream's source domain as an exception domain on App Transport Security Settings on info.plist. While testing, I set "Allow Arbitrary Loads" to YES. Before I did this, the stream didn't come through at all.

*On Android:*
Use the new exoplayer variant introduced in react-native-video 1.0. Here's how to enable that: [#426 (comment)](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/pull/426#issuecomment-272765610)

Answer (score 0):

React Native does not support it.

I have not used this, but you may find what you need in this plugin: https://github.com/ms88privat/react-native-video-gstreamer

Comment: That project is no longer maintained as mentioned on your provided link page. Any other option?